# Printing substring using search method

Tags: python, html

I have the source code of a web page defined as a string type variable. I know that a certain date will apear on the source code. I want to print out the first link that appears before that date. This link can be found in between apostrophes (`""`), here's the code:

```
import requests
from datetime import date
import re

link = "https://www.google.com.mx/search?biw=1535&bih=799&tbm=nws&q=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&oq=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&gs_l=serp.3...1632004.1638057.0.1638325.24.24.0.0.0.0.257.2605.0j15j2.17.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..8.0.0.Nl4BZQWwR3o"
fetch_data =requests.get(link)
content = str((fetch_data.content))

#this is the source code as a string

Months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
today = date.today()
A= ("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1],today.day))
a=today.day
B= A in content
if B == True:
    B = ("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1], a))
else:
    while B == False:
        a = a - 1
        B = ("%s %s" % (Months[today.month - 1], a))

#the B variable is the string date that will appear in the variable string content

c= ('"https:')
Z= ("%s(.*)%s" % (c,B))
result = re.search(Z, content)
print (result)
```

This is what I tried: I looked for the substring in between variables `c` and `B`, code didn't find anything

If anyone looks for the source code from [the link](https://www.google.com.mx/search?biw=1535&bih=799&tbm=nws&q=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&oq=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&gs_l=serp.3...1632004.1638057.0.1638325.24.24.0.0.0.0.257.2605.0j15j2.17.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..8.0.0.Nl4BZQWwR3o) you'll find that today's date "December 27" appears only once and before that the link I am interested in appears as "https://www.zacks.com/commentary/98986/new-strong-buy-stocks-for-december-27th".

Can someone help me automating python to define this link and print it?

Comment: The `while B == False:` loop never searches for `B` in `content`.

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse HTML is generally a bad idea. Use a DOM parser library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar said, you would be better off using a DOM parser such as [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Here is an example

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urlparse
from datetime import datetime

link = "https://www.google.com.mx/search?biw=1535&bih=799&tbm=nws&q=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&oq=%22New+Strong+Buy%22+site%3A+zacks.com&gs_l=serp.3...1632004.1638057.0.1638325.24.24.0.0.0.0.257.2605.0j15j2.17.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..8.0.0.Nl4BZQWwR3o"

r = requests.get(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

search = datetime.today().strftime("%B %d")
print("Searching for {}".format(search))

result = None
for i in soup.findAll('h3'):
    linkText = i.getText()
    if search in linkText:
        result = i.find('a').get('href')
        result = result.split('?')[-1]
        result = urlparse.parse_qs(result)['q'][0]
        break

print(result)
```

The output I receive is

```
Searching for December 27
https://www.zacks.com/commentary/98986/new-strong-buy-stocks-for-december-27th
```